# Scala List Comprehensions

Tags: scala, list-comprehension, yield, scala-2.9

I'm trying to generate a list in scala according to the formula:

```
for n > 1 f(n) = 4*n^2 - 6*n + 6 and for n == 1 f(n) = 1
```

currently I have:

```
def lGen(end: Int): List[Int] = {
    for { n <- List.range(3 , end + 1 , 2) } yields { 4*n*n - 6*n - 6 }
}
```

For end = 5 this would give the list:

```
List(24 , 76)
```

Right now I'm stuck on trying to find a gracefull way to make this function give

```
List(1 , 24 , 74)
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

-Lee

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this:

```
scala> def lGen(end: Int): List[Int] =
         1 :: List.range(3, end+1, 2).map(n => 4*n*n - 6*n + 6)

scala> lGen(5)
res0: List[Int] = List(1, 24, 76)
```

Comment: What is the :: operator doing in this case?

Comment: It's a "cons" operator, i.e. it prepends the `1` to the list.

Answer (score 13):

I'd separate out the "formula" from the list generation:

```
val f : Int => Int = {
  case 1 => 1
  case x if x > 1 => 4*x*x - 6*x + 6
}

def lGen(end: Int) = (1 to end by 2 map f).toList
```

or

```
def lGen(end: Int) = List.range(1, end + 1, 2) map f
```

Comment: I like how this approach keeps the definition intact.

Comment: is it change the result if I write instead of `case x if x > 1`, `case x > 1`?